# Why emacs can not see outer variable in lambda function?

Tags: variables

I had a simple config to set `fci-rule-column` to different values depend on file types:

```lisp
(use-package fill-column-indicator
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq fci-rule-color "LightSlateBlue")
  (setq fci-handle-truncate-lines t)
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                (setq-default fci-rule-column 79)
                                (fci-mode t)))
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (setq-default fci-rule-column 80)
                           (fci-mode t))))
```

You can see every time I add new file type, I have to repeat the work `(add-hook ...)`. So I decide to refactor the code:

```lisp
(use-package fill-column-indicator
  :ensure t
  :config
  (setq fci-rule-color "LightSlateBlue")
  (setq fci-handle-truncate-lines t)
  (defun my/fci-config (mode num)
    (add-hook mode (lambda ()
                     (progn
                       (setq-default fci-rule-column num)
                       (fci-mode t)))))
  (let (mode-config-hash)
    (setq mode-config-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
    (puthash 'python-mode-hook 79 mode-config-hash)
    (puthash 'c-mode-hook 80 mode-config-hash)
    (puthash 'cperl-mode-hook 80 mode-config-hash)
    (maphash (lambda (k v) (my/fci-config k v)) mode-config-hash)))
```

With this approach, I only to put the mode and the number to hash table `mode-config-hash` when I configure setting for new file type.

But the code above did not work. I opened a Python or C file and the `fci-mode` was not enabled.

I try some debugging and realized that the line:

```
(setq-default fci-rule-column num)
```

did not ran correctly. If I change it to an integer value:

```
(setq-default fci-rule-column 79)
```

Then it worked.

So why did emacs *see* my variable? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Start reading about "dynamic binding" vs "lexical binding". The former is the default.

Comment: @phils: yeah, I read it before, but use `let` or even `let-lexical` with no luck.

Comment: A `let` binding is dynamic, unless lexical binding has been enabled for the library as a whole. If you used `lexical-let` with no success, show your code. Backquoting is a common solution in this sort of situation.

Comment: @cuonglm Do you have lexical binding enabled in the file containing this code?

Comment: @phils: Yeah, the `lexical-let` actually worked. I have some mis-typing in my attempt. It's now in my config https://github.com/Gnouc/emacs.d/commit/df00db9ed1dbbe40eeaf838b122288b3615bff9a . Thanks for your information.

Comment: @lunaryorn: No, I did not enable lexical binding. And `lexical-let` work, my bad for previous attempt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either enable lexical binding as a file-local variable in the file's first line, as described in the Elisp manual, node [Using Lexical Binding](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Lexical-Binding.html), or just use this with dynamic binding (which is the default):

```
`(lambda ()
   (setq-default fci-rule-column ',num)
   (fci-mode t))
```

(The `'` before `,num` is not needed, except if you are unsure whether `NUM` will be a number and you want to go ahead and assign whatever is passed as `NUM` to variable `fci-rule-column`.)

This *substitutes*, at the time `my/fci-config` is invoked, the *value* of `NUM` that is passed to it, so there is no free variable in the resulting function (lambda form).  The result of this code is a *list*.  For example, if 42 is passed to `my/fci-config` as the value of its second arg then this is the resulting list:

```
(lambda ()
  (setq-default fci-rule-column '42)
  (fci-mode t))
```

The list will **not** be byte-compiled, because it is created (and evaluated) at runtime.

- That's the downside -- not as efficient, by default.  But you can byte-compile it explicitly using function `byte-compile`.  And this is the only downside.  Any other advantages of lexical binding (both lexical and dynamic binding have their advantages) do *not* apply here wrt variable `NUM`, since that variable has been eliminated.
- The upside here is that the function that is the lambda form does *not at all need* any such variable, *as a variable*.  That is, it **does not use the variable** *as such*; it needs only its (predefined) value.  If the lambda form, or other code that it invokes, actually needed to do something with its free variable `NUM`, as a variable (e.g., set it, for other code), then it would make sense to keep it in the lambda body as a (free) variable.  But in this case all you need is its value (which was passed to `my/fci-config`).

Comment: Yeah, and also using `lexcal-let` worked. See https://github.com/Gnouc/emacs.d/commit/df00db9ed1dbbe40eeaf838b122288b3615bff9a

Comment: Yes, `lexical-let` is a local alternative to turning on `lexical-binding` in a file. And a good one.